# How to calculate the Half Width for an OBB Object 2D

Tags: c#, xna, windows-runtime, bounding-box, sharpdx

I am programming a SharpDX.Toolkit Game in 2D. So far so good, but when I try to initialize the OBB Object, the third Parameter requires a Vector2, wich is named Half-Width. I haven't any Idea of what this Vector consists. Does anyone has an idea?
Here is my Code:

```
OBB obb = new OBB(new Vector2(Pos.X, Pos.Y), rotation, new Vector2(HalfWidth));
```

More Info: The sprite is rotated around the origin Pos.X,Pos.Y.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming this is OrientedBoundingBox, I do not see a constructor option that takes 3 parameters. What object is this? I highly suggest looking at the documentation.

Comment: I use a class from the internet it's located here http://1drv.ms/1CnT56V

Comment: Looking at that class, it's just your desired size divided by 2. Not sure why they chose to go that route, but they did. So if you want a 2x2 box, use `new Vector2(1,1)`.

Comment: I thought this too, but the dectection doesn't work with this value. Maybe the OBB class from the Internet is incorrect. Do you have any other classes, wich I could use?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Was merely doing Google searches and using your linked class for information.

Comment: Maybe it is the origin

Comment: I've tested this, but it doesn't work, too.